# Laravel deleting all pivot table values

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have two models [Tag and Topic].

TAG:

```
class Tag extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function topics(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany('\App\Topic','tag_topic')->withPivot('topic_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

TOPIC:

```
class Topic extends Model{
    protected $fillable = [ 'user_id', 'creator_id', 'name', 'category_id'];

    public function tags(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany('\App\Tag', 'tag_topic')->withPivot('topic_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Then I have the migrations for both tables and the pivot table.
[TAG]

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->unique();
        $table->string('name') -> unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

[TOPIC]

```
Schema::create('topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->unique();
        $table->integer('user_id') -> unsigned();
        $table->integer('creator_id') -> unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->enum('status', ['pending', 'accepted']);
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')->on('creators')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('creators')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

[PIVOT]

```
Schema::create('tag_topic', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->unique();
        $table->integer('tag_id') -> unsigned() -> nullable();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->integer('topic_id') -> unsigned() -> nullable();
        $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('topics')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->integer('category_id') -> unsigned() -> nullable();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('category_id')->on('topics')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My question is, once I delete any TOPIC no matter which one, it automatically deletes EVERYTHING like, literally everything from the pivot table.

What I´m doing in order to delete a topic is this:

```
$topic = Topic::where('name', '=', $request -> topic_name) -> first();
$category = Category::where('id', '=', $topic->category_id) -> first();
$topic -> delete();
```

But it deletes everything, any help, am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here on the topic schema:

```
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
$table->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')->on('creators')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('creators')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

You're cascading from one deleted topic to any user, creator, or category that will then cascade back onto the topic table related to all of those deleted users, creators, and categories, which then just goes in a loop until the entire table is deleted. I'd remove some of those cascade effects.

Comment: I think the same